# Wrong answer in recursion/memoization - (Leetcode) Maximum Bags With Full Capacity of Rocks

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, memoization

I was looking at this problem on leetcode:

https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-bags-with-full-capacity-of-rocks/

In short, we are given two arrays, the capacity array that represents the maximum number of rocks a bag can hold and a rocks array that represents the current status of each bag, we are also given some additional rocks to fill the bags to their capacity. Return the maximum number of bags that can be filled.

```
Input: capacity = [2,3,4,5], rocks = [1,2,4,4], additionalRocks = 2
Output: 3
Explanation:
Place 1 rock in bag 0 and 1 rock in bag 1.
The number of rocks in each bag are now [2,3,4,4].
Bags 0, 1, and 2 have full capacity.
There are 3 bags at full capacity, so we return 3.
It can be shown that it is not possible to have more than 3 bags at full capacity.
Note that there may be other ways of placing the rocks that result in an answer of 3.
```

I know that this problem can be solved greedily with sorting but I wanted to try a recursive solution on the idea that there are two choices, fill a bag or dont fill a bag and the same problem is repeated for the next index.

**Unable to figure out if I am wrong at the recursion part or the memoization part**

```java
class Solution {
    int[] capacities;
    int[] current;
    
    private int helper(int i,int addrocks){
        if(i>=capacities.length) return 0;
        
        if(addrocks <= 0) return 0;
        
        int ans1=0;
        if(addrocks>=(capacities[i]-current[i])){
            ans1 = 1 + helper(i+1,addrocks-(capacities[i]-current[i]));
        }
        
       int ans2 = helper(i+1,addrocks);
        
        return Math.max(ans1,ans2);
    }
    
    public int maximumBags(int[] capacity, int[] rocks, int additionalRocks) {
        capacities = capacity;
        current = rocks;
        return helper(0,additionalRocks);
    }
}
```

As expected I got a Time limit exceeded error due to exponential complexity. So I thought of memoization using a hashmap. I use a string containing index i and the extra rocks as the look up key as java doesnt have a pair like cpp. I just add this lookup part to the above code, the memoization approach is as follows:

```java
class Solution {
    int[] capacities;
    int[] current;
    Map<String,Integer> m;
    
    private int helper(int i,int addrocks){
        if(i>=capacities.length) return 0;
        
        if(addrocks <= 0) return 0;
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(i); sb.append("i"); sb.append(addrocks); sb.append("r");
        String x = sb.toString();
        if(m.containsKey(x)){
            return m.get(x);
        }
        
        int ans1=0;
        if(addrocks>=(capacities[i]-current[i])){
            ans1 = 1 + helper(i+1,addrocks-(capacities[i]-current[i]));
        }
        
        int ans2 = helper(i+1,addrocks);
        int maxans = Math.max(ans1,ans2);
        m.put(x,maxans);
        return maxans;
    }
    
    public int maximumBags(int[] capacity, int[] rocks, int additionalRocks) {
        capacities = capacity;
        current = rocks;
        m = new HashMap<>();
        return helper(0,additionalRocks);
    }
}
```

This code only passes 27/79 test cases. **I am unable to figure out if I am wrong at the recursion part or the memoization part as the test cases are too large.**

submission url for reference: https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/866167322/

Answer (score 0):

Your aproach with recursion will not work because the memoization doesn't really help that much. Imagine having N times capacities 1 and N/2 rocks: at index N/2 the helper is called with rock numbers from 0 to N/2. You are checking so many permutations. It could be improved by checking if it is possible to get a better result than the best so far, but it will not solve the problem.

Btw. it would be faster to just concatenate the string because you are not adding to it in each loop but creating a new one each iteration. Also the append method in StringBuilder can be chained.

If you need a Pair, there are a lot of choices, we mostly used the one from [Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) which works fine, but I can't say anything about the others.